gamm and gamm4 give very different smooth term results for mixed models with factor-smooth interaction
I am analyzing an longitudinal dataset which has two groups (patient vs controls; ordered factor) with brain volume data over time. Participants entered the study at different ages and have varied number of follow-up visits and duration. My goal is to test if the groups differ in their longitudinal trajectories of brain volume, and I would like to account for subject-level random intercepts and slopes.
I have been experimenting with different ways of fitting my data (R's gam, gamm, and gamm4), but they all give different results. I am quite new to the gam world, and I am hoping to get some help on (1) identifying how I may have inadvertently specified models differently, (2) choosing the right model.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!
gam: (long_age = longitudinal age; sex = covariate, factor; subject = subject ID)
gam_model <- gam(volume ~ 
                   s(long_age) + 
                   s(long_age, by = ExperimentalGroup) + 
                   ExperimentalGroup + 
                   sex + 
                   s(subject, bs = "re") +
                   s(subject, long_age, bs = "fs"),
                  data = dataset,
                 method = "REML")

gamm:
gamm_model <- gamm(volume ~ 
                    s(long_age, k = 10, fx = FALSE) + 
                    s(long_age, by = ExperimentalGroup, k = 10, fx = FALSE) + 
                    ExperimentalGroup +
                    sex,
                    random = list(subject = ~ 1 + long_age),
                    data = dataset)

gamm4:
gamm4_model <- gamm4(volume ~ 
                  s(long_age, k = 10, bs = "tp") +
                  s(long_age, by = ExperimentalGroup, k = 10, bs = "tp") + 
                  ExperimentalGroup + 
                  sex, 
                  data = dataset,
                  random = ~(long_age|subject),
                  REML = TRUE)

Here are the model results:
The focal effect is s(long_age):ExperimentalGroup1. Note the wildly varying p-values for the smooth terms (esp. wrt gamm4).
gam:
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.6110680  0.0035608 171.609   <2e-16 ***
ExperimentalGroup.L -0.0074694  0.0037308  -2.002   0.0471 *  
Sex1                 0.0007774  0.0050802   0.153   0.8786    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                  edf  Ref.df      F p-value    
s(long_age)                     3.678   4.397 16.395 < 2e-16 ***
s(long_age):ExperimentalGroup1  1.000   1.000 11.193 0.00105 ** 
s(Subject)                     62.874  78.000 18.242 < 2e-16 ***
s(Subject,long_age)            21.330 579.000  2.965 1.00000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.915   Deviance explained = 94.8%
-REML = -641.36  Scale est. = 7.0958e-05  n = 236

gamm:
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Parametric coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.6110916  0.0035536 171.966   <2e-16 ***
ExperimentalGroup.L -0.0072646  0.0037272  -1.949   0.0525 .  
Sex1                 0.0007181  0.0050386   0.143   0.8868    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                 edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(long_age)                    3.738  3.738 20.99  < 2e-16 ***
s(long_age):ExperimentalGroup1 1.000  1.000 11.87 0.000678 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.397   
  Scale est. = 7.4195e-05  n = 236

And gamm4:
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Parametric coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.610987   0.002629 232.428  < 2e-16 ***
ExperimentalGroup.L -0.007303   0.002483  -2.941  0.00361 ** 
Sex1                 0.000807   0.001517   0.532  0.59529    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                 edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(long_age)                    4.605  4.605 116.8  <2e-16 ***
s(long_age):ExperimentalGroup1 1.000  1.000 122.7  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.393   
lmer.REML = -1281.2  Scale est. = 7.4096e-05  n = 236
```


These models have very different smooths for the effects of long_age. First, they use different k values (the default is 10), so that is one reason why they can differ. Also using fx = TRUE will turn off the penalization altogether, which I doubt is what you want. Finally, the gamm4 model uses cubic regression splines as the basis, while the others use the default thin plate basis. I'm also unsure if you need both s(subject, bs = "re") and s(subject, long_age, bs = "re") in the first model, perhaps the second term is enough (but Gavin Simpson should be able to clarify)

@NicholasClark if you want random intercepts and slopes (uncorrelated) then you need both terms; s(subject, long_age, bs = "re") will just you a separate slope per subject.

Beyond all the differences @NicholasClark mentions, it makes little sense to me to model the main effects of long_age as smooth and then restrict the subject-specific effects to be linear (implying all the subjects long_age curves are the same shape just differing in overall slope). If you think effects are smooth, consider using a bs = "fs" smooth for subject-specific smooths. Also, don't do something just because others in your field have used it; k = 4 is very restrictive & much of the theory behind GAMs requires that you don't undersmooth, which this choice of k could lead to

@adrianneurosci Edit your original question with the corrected models please. It still doesn't look like you are fitting like for like models. Only when you are fitting exactly the same model in all three functions can we start to discuss differences between model fits

@GavinSimpson Thank you. Please see the edited version - I am trying to catch how I might have inadvertently modeled different models differently - any further input is greatly appreciated!

Your gamm() is fitting with ML while the gamm4() is using REML. Also, your two GAMMs are not the same as the gam(). It would be helpful if you used the same formula in both - so it you have random smooths ("fs") in the gam() use the same in the two GAMMs. Like I said, I simply don't see any reason to model main effects as smooth and subject-specific effects as linear, which is that you are doing here in the GAMMs.

I see - I totally didn't realize that's what the GAMMs are doing; thanks for pointing that out.
